# Должен: что за слово такое?

Tags: глаголы

В предложении:

> Ты **должен** вымыть посуду.

Что такое слово *должен*? В словарях нашёл, что это краткая форма прилагательного, не имеющего полных форм. При этом можно частично заменить аналогами — *тебе следует*, *ты обязан*, *тебе необходимо*.

Сильно напоминает модальные глаголы в английском.

Так всё же, что это за словоформа такая и какое она занимает место в русском языке?

Answer (score 3):

Вы же сами сказали, что краткое прилагательное, не имеющее полной формы. Краткие прилагательные, утратив способность изменяться по падежам и выступая, как правило, в роли сказуемого, иногда приобретают и новое лексическое значение, отличное от значений полных прилагательных.

Прилагательное должен в отдельных фразеологических оборотах употребляется и в полной форме: в должной мере, должным образом и т.д., но имеет другое значение. Должен - это "обязан"(обязан что-то сделать или обязан уплатить долг), а должный - "такой, как надо".

От него - вводное "должно быть" - это уже модальное слово. Есть устаревшее слово "дОлжно"- это категория состояния: Так не  дОлжно поступать.

Таких прилагательных много. Разными по значению могут стать прилагательные видный и виден, правый и прав, способный и способен и т.п. Причём такие прилагательные, как горазд, надобен, рад и некоторые другие, употребляются только в краткой форме: Здравствуй, Балда-мужичок, какой тебе надобен оброк? (П.), А разве пригожий Лель горазд на песни? (А. Остр.).